# Sweetalert as a whole component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert

I have been using Sweetalerts here and there and I wonder if it's possible to have a swal as a whole component.

So that I can pass props and states to it. Just have it function as a normal component.

I've searched online, but didn't find much so I wanted to give one last try here.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is this similar to what you're asking: https://github.com/chentsulin/sweetalert-react ?

Answer (score 1):

I first want to thank Jackowski who commented a github link to `sweetalert-react`.

I found out that the original Sweetalert API doesn't provide a way to use a `swal` as a whole component so what I need to go with is `sweetalert-react`: https://github.com/chentsulin/sweetalert-react

There's also one for redux: https://github.com/chentsulin/react-redux-sweetalert

Hope this will help someone.